# Why I cannot get return value from the stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure like this,

```
USE MyDataBaseName
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE h_sp_find_exist
@in_name varchar,@in_counterparty varchar,
@out_recordsNum int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @out_recordsNum = COUNT(*)
    FROM TMyTableName
    WHERE Name=@in_name AND Counterparty=@in_counterparty
RETURN @out_recordsNum 
END
```

I always get 0 from the return value.
What's wrong with it?

The execute code:

```
use MyDataBaseName
go
declare @retRecordNum int
execute h_sp_find_exist 'myName', '50139', @retRecordNum OUTPUT
select @retRecordNum as 'RecordNumber'
```

if I just run the sql code, 
select count (*)
where name='myName' and counterparty='50139', it works, and result is 1

Comment: You don't need the return. Can you show the code how you read the value?

Comment: How do you check the returned value?

Comment: And if you just need one output, do it without the output parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input parameters are being truncated, because you've not supplied a length for varchar, and the [default is 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). (You also as others have said, don't need the return statement):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE h_sp_find_exist
@in_name varchar(20),@in_counterparty varchar(20), --<-- changes here
@out_recordsNum int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @out_recordsNum = COUNT(*)
    FROM TMyTable
    WHERE Name=@in_name AND Counterparty=@in_counterparty
END
```

[Return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) sets the exit code for the stored procedure. This can only ever be an integer, and would generally be used to indicate success or failure. You can obtain the value from a return by assigning it as part of your exec statement:

```
declare @retRecordNum int
declare @returnCode int
execute @returnCode = h_sp_find_exist 'myName', '50139', @retRecordNum OUTPUT
select @retRecordNum as 'RecordNumber'
```

Here, `@returnCode` would be assigned whatever value was passed to the `return` statement

Answer (score 0):

Write your return outside the `End` and try

```
USE MyTable
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE h_sp_find_exist
@in_name varchar,@in_counterparty varchar,
@out_recordsNum int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @out_recordsNum = COUNT(*)
    FROM TMyTable
    WHERE Name=@in_name AND Counterparty=@in_counterparty
END
RETURN @out_recordsNum
```

Comment: hi, it still have the problem. I think it's the assignment expression problem. Thanks

Comment: Ya, @iAsk follow like what ibram said, dont put any output parameter and try.

Comment: No, iAsk needs the output param. I think damien has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set @output =(select count(*) from table)